# High cpu utilization when combining png into pdf by itextsharp

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext, cpu-usage

When combining PNGs into PDF by itextsharp, the CPU utilization is very high(about 26%). I don't know why. Any suggestions as to how I might reduce CPU utilization? 
Here is the code.

```
PdfWriter pdfWrite = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(PDFFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite));
document.Open();
iTextSharp.text.Image image;
document.AddTitle(_book.Title);
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(file.FullName);
    document.SetPageSize(new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(image.Width, image.Height));
    image.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Image.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    document.NewPage();
    document.Add(image);
 }
```

Comment: Uhhh...you're using the CPU to *do* something (convert a PNG into a PDF). The only problem here would be if the CPU were *not* being utilized.

Comment: What I mean is how to make the code more efficient.

Comment: How do you know it's *not* efficient? Efficient code doesn't mean that it doesn't utilize the CPU. It means that it does so efficiently. Is the code running too *slowly*?

Comment: @CodyGray: Many tools that convert PNGs into a PDF online don't utilize the CPU so much. So I am wondering whether there are problems with my code. Is that any better way to convert PNGs into a PDF? Sorry for my poor English. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: So maybe those tools are inefficient. You are avoiding the question: is the code running too slowly?